# Locking golang recursive map

Tags: go, locking, goroutine

I have a recursive map-like structure which looks like this:

```
type RecurseTable struct {
    Table map[string]*RecurseTable
    // Other fields
    sync.RWMutex
}
```

If I am going to access this structure from multiple goroutines, how exactly do I go about locking it? Let's say I'm reading from the top-level map and writing to the third-level, nested map. Is it accurate to say that this wouldn't cause any problems because changing the third level (and hence indirecting through two pointers) shouldn't affect the top level map?

Similarly, if I have a pool of goroutines all modifying information in the second-level, nested struct, would it be the case I only need to lock each second-level map because the top-level map only contains a pointer to the nested RecurseTable? Or is it the case that I have to lock both the top-level map as well as the nested struct, because the struct could somehow be reallocated in memory, causing a change to the pointer stored as a value in the top-level map?

Another situation would be adding keys to the top-level map whilst reading from the second-level struct. Is it safe to assume that any reorganising of the top-level map due to the new key wouldn't affect the location of the second-level struct in memory, and hence it wouldn't be necessary to lock the struct whilst reading?

My goal here is to minimise global locks of the entire recursive structure so that my goroutines can work on different parts of the structure in parallel, with minimal lock contention. I guess the core of my question is about how maps in Golang resize.

Comment: Once you have a pointer to a deep map you do not need to worry about the layers on top: Objects are not moved in memory; once you have a pointer to an object this pointer is valid. It doesn't matter if some other object contains a (copy) of the same pointer value (here the map buckets). But **any** write access has to be protected by holding the lock of the appropriate level. Why not run your code under the race detector.

Comment: Yup, I tried it and its all good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Go maps in action](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) blogpost :

> *Maps are not safe for concurrent use*: it's not defined what happens when you read and write to them simultaneously. If you need to read from and write to a map from concurrently executing goroutines, the accesses must be mediated by some kind of synchronization mechanism. One common way to protect maps is with `sync.RWMutex`.

As you are feeding the map pointers to other maps, you can safely lock a map independently from the others (siblings or descendants): even if you delete a map entry while using its descendants, it won't be a problem since their references will be kept until you release the pointers (ie the var holding them is deleted).

Comment: Well as he said, he wants to write to the map, that means replace the pointer that is the value. So while there is no race condition, the question is still, if access to a referenced sub map should prevent a pointer to it from being replaced in some upper table. 

Maybe it will become unreachable.

That depends on the application, so more information is needed from the OP.

Comment: Hmm, I think it locking at a particular level should suffice then. Each map is only created once and never replaced with a new map -> entries are just added over time, and the other fields of the struct are written to as well.

Comment: Ah, I see - then go for it.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to not export the Table member and provide Get/Set methods that lock appropriately. For example:

```
type RecurseTable struct {
    table map[string]*RecurseTable
    // Other fields
    sync.RWMutex
}

func New() *RecurseTable {
    return &RecurseTable{
        table: make(map[string]*RecurseTable),
    }
}

func (r *RecurseTable) Get(key string) (*RecurseTable, bool) {
    r.RLock()
    defer r.RUnlock()
    return r.table[key]
}

func (r *RecurseTable) Set(key string, value *RecurseTable) {
    r.Lock()
    defer r.Unlock()
    r.table[key] = value
}
```

This way the only way to access the map's data is via the methods which guard access to the map. Each value is then guarded independently.

Comment: OP needs to lock every map in the hierarchy at the point of access since none of the maps are thread safe. In the OP's question he can read lock the parent and obtain map values in two different goroutines. Accessing these values is not threadsafe, they need to be guarded.

Comment: I guess you will have to edit your answer in order for me to be able to undo my downvote. I'm so sorry...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this would definitely be the way I would do it normally, as it guarantees safety. However my main priority right now is efficiency, so I think I will stick to manual locking so I can do successive reads/writes without the overhead of locking and unlocking.